# How many of these cosets of $\mathbb{Z}^2/H$ are distinct?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

[image]

My answer:

Since all of $(1\; 6), (3\; 5)$ and $(7\; 11)$ are found in $H$, then none of them are distinct. Does this make sense? I'm not sure I understood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those vectors are contained in $H$ since $H$ is generated by $(2, 0)^T$ and $(0, 2)^T$, so $H$ only contains vectors where both entries are zero modulo two. Consider all of the vectors modulo two. Notice that adding multiples of two to the entries of the first vector lets you get any vector of the form $(2k +1, 2m)$ for $k,m\in \mathbb{Z}$, but for the second two, you can generate only vectors with odd entries.

Comment: I was thinking that (2, 12) for example is the same as (1, 6) for some reason. Anyway, so the answer is that only the first coset is distinct, right?

Comment: Yeah. I had a pretty dumb mistake in the answer at first. The second and third cosets are the sets of vectors with odd entries. The first is as described in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

While the question has already been answered I'll give my two cents just so options exists. As stated none is in $H$ as $H=2\mathbb{Z}\oplus2\mathbb{Z}$, however to check which are distinct we can simply check what their difference is, we know that $O\pm O = E$ and $O\pm E= O$ with $O$ being some odd number and $E$ even. As addition is done componentwise we have that the left two must result in both components being even in their difference, that is because all their entries are odd, and as such we have $(3,5)-(7,11)\in H$ and as such are not distinct. for the first one we notice one of the components is even and as such it's difference with any of the other two will give an odd entry and as such it is not equivalent to any of them and is distinct from the other two.